# Problem with exporting commands to other batch file

Tags: batch-file

When I use the command `echo pause >nul >>batchfile.bat` from a cmd program it only prints out `pause` in batchfile.bat. How can I make it print `pause >nul` in batchfile.bat?

I've tried putting it in `""`, `''`, and doubling the arrows for nul `>>nul` and `>>>nul` but it printed either

> pause; 'pause or showed an error "unexpected >`

at `>>>nul`.

```
echo pause >nul >>startserver.bat
```

I took it from my batch file which creates a command `pause >nul` and writes it into startserver.bat, however I only get a `pause` without `>nul` as output on startserver.bat

I need it to give output `pause >nul` in startserver.bat.
What I get is only `pause`, the `>nul` gets basically lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`>` is getting interpreted as redirection (and immediately overridden by the following `>>`). You have to escape it to make it interpreted literally. CMD's escape character is the caret, so do this:

```
echo pause ^>nul >>startserver.bat
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly for me.